# Redis returning cursor 0 even after containg keys

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a keys in redis as

```
pool-1:2c3aab73-d46a-4491-9e98-45eb6b5b6608
pool-1:65e10493-da51-4fff-b744-47880e5b67db
pool-1:b9429608-6f6e-4301-9a35-cda83b762f92
```

and this is my SCAN query

`SCAN 0 MATCH pool-1:* COUNT 1`
I run the same query further after the returned cursor from the previous results. But still the results return with cursor `0` and no results.

I'm trying it in node.js This is my code.

```
let cursor=1
while (cursor != 0 && !stop) {
            result = await redis_ops.SCAN(cursor, hash, count);
            cursor = result[0];
        }
```

I even tried the query from `redis-cli` but still the same problem.

Comment: You need to start with cursor `0`. In your code above you've started with `1`.

Comment: The cursor is 0, it is the first argument.

Comment: As @KevinChristopherHenry said you need to start with 0, i.e. `let cursor =0` in L:1